# User Admin - View Permissions when 750 is used for home

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, users

As the main admin of a server, I want to make it so that users can't see each others home folders. (so I chmod 750 the home folder which includes me, so I can see mine but can't see other people's).

I realise I can 'su' to change in to the users if I need to see in their folders, but I am presuming that root would be able to move in to that folder and see the contents, but obviously I can't 'sudo cd' or 'sudo ls'.

So I was thinking of having all users in a 'user group' which I could be a member of. Or is this a terrible idea? Should I just 'su' or is there a way around this that I can't think of?

I did search for solutions but as you can imagine 99.9% of the solutions you find are not talking about this specific scenario, more permissions in general.

So to summarise: I want to be able to see what's in user's folders without having to 'su', but leave other users unable to see in each other's folders.

Comment: Why can't you `sudo ls` if you're the admin of the system?

Comment: Apologies per below my problem was actually that I cant as a normal user get in to the folder to 'sudo ls'. It was poorly explained. :)

Comment: oh damn im dumb, I could just sudo ls /home/userfolder
Sorry complete linux noob >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to accomplish this without resorting to ACLs is, Permissions set to `750` and your username being a member of every other user's primary group. For instance, lets say you have these users:

```
me
user1
otheruser
```

`/home` will look something like this:

```
drwxr-x---  2 me        me         4096 Mar  3 12:14 me
drwxr-x--- 24 user1     user1      4096 Apr  8 05:33 user1
drwxr-x---  2 otheruser otheruser  4096 Feb 11 09:27 otheruser
```

and in your group file you will see these

```
me:x:500:
user1:x:501:
otheruser:x:502:
```

and you are going to add yourself to other users' primary groups and your group fill will look like this:

```
me:x:500:
user1:x:501:me
otheruser:x:502:me
```

Comment: Thanks, so in honesty 'su' is prob a better option until I learn some more.

Comment: my sentiments exactly. I do not like co-mingling groups either. Also, `sudo ls` is a valid command that you can run, while `sudo cd` is NOT!

Comment: yeah so the problem is I cant get in to the folder to 'sudo ls' actually not that 'sudo ls' is wrong. (Thanks for that). 

A more elegant solution is possibly to just 'sudo -s' for the duration of whatever I need to do I guess.

Comment: oh damn im dumb, I could just sudo ls /home/userfolder

Answer (score 0):

I Wouldn't advice to become a member of all user groups, but have a look at extended ACLs instead.

Read about `setfacl` and `getfacl` on the web or the man pages and set default ACLs which allow you to enter the other home directories.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i got that impression but had to give the answer to the other gent as he was really first. (Id have upvoted you as well but .. eh i dont even have 15 yet to do it :D).